# $\sum_{k=1}^n [X_k-E(X_k)]$ converge in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

$\{X_n\}$ are independent, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty Var(X_k)<\infty$,prove
$$\sum_{k=1}^n [X_k-E(X_k)]
$$converge in probability.

---

I have tried chebyshev inequality, but it's too loose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG shift so that $\mathbb E[X_n]=0$ for all $n$. Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$. Then we can just apply Chebyshev's inequality: for $1\leq m\leq n$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(\lvert S_n-S_m\rvert>\epsilon)=\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert\sum_{k=m+1}^nX_k\right\rvert>\epsilon\right)&\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{k=m+1}^nX_k\right)\\
&\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\sum_{k>m}\operatorname{Var}(X_k).
\end{align*}
The RHS converges to $0$ as $m\to\infty$, since $\sum\operatorname{Var}(X_k)<\infty$, so we're done.

In fact, from one of many lemmas due to Levy, the independence of the $X_k$ implies that we in fact have almost sure convergence too.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mathsf{E}X_i)$. Then $\{S_n\}$ converges in $L^2$ (and in probability) because
$$
\operatorname{Var}(S_n-S_m)\to 0\quad\text{as}\quad n,m\to\infty,
$$
and so $\{S_n\}$ is $L^2$-Cauchy convergent.